# How to begin fixing XSS hole in website

Tags: web, security, xss

I've never dealt with XSS before, but I just received a comment from a vistor that my website has XSS vulnerabilities.

He was nice enough to provide me with the string that activated a prompt box that displays the user's cookies. 
I have a lot code within this website and webapp, how do I find this and fix it? Where do I start?

Comment: What platform does your site run on?

Comment: The OWASP Top 10 article is a good place to start in understanding XSS. After a quick overview, checking the prevention cheat sheets might be a quick way to get started finding and fixing. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-A3-Cross-Site_Scripting_(XSS)

Comment: The site is built on HTML5 Boiler Plate. There are plenty of third party libraries in PHP and JS. I'm just curious as to how to find out which one it is.

Answer (score 0):

OWASP also provided API to prevent this kind of attacks. Those API is written in several Programming languages.

You can download those API from [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/ESAPI).

Why don't you go and download that API (in your preferred programming language) and use if for sanitizing the user input.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to reduce (not stop) XSS vulnerabilities is to HTML encode all your output.  You should also scrub the data that someone submits for XSS vulnerabilities. On the .NET platform you can use the antixss library, on PHP you could use strip_tags(), there should be something for whatever platform you're using but they're not going to be 100%.  And check out the [OWASP XSS Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) at https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

XSS can be tricky, Stack Overflow, Gmail, Outlook Web Access all had XSS vulnerabilities in the past.  But if you follow the cheat sheet for all your input and output you should be able to greatly reduce the problem.  Search your code for any echo or response.write or

```
<?= ?>, <%= %>
```

After that move on to the input points, look for any Request.Form or $_GET or $_POST or however you're getting your data input.